# Conditional string replacement in r

Tags: r, string, dplyr, stringr, mapply

I have a dataframe that contains a column with brokernames, which are handwritten by customers, that I would like to go through in order to replace the handwritten brokernames with unique brokernames that I have in a list.

A snippet of my data looks like this:

```
Data <- data.frame(Date = c("01-10-2020", "01-10-2020", "01-11-2020", "01-11-2020"), 
                   Broker = c("RealEstate", "REALestate", "Estate", "ESTATE"))
```

My list of unique broker names looks like this:

```
Unique_brokers <- list("REALESTATE", "ESTATE")
```

Based on some sort of pattern-recognition, I would like to replace the brokernames in my `Data` dataframe with the unique brokernames in my `Unique_brokers` list.

I've partially managed to do this somewhat manually using a combination of `case_when` and `str_detect` from `dplyr` and `stringr` respectively.

```
Data <- Data %>%
   mutate("UniqueBroker" = case_when(str_detect(Broker, regex("realestate", ignore_case=T))~"REALEASTE",
                                  str_detect(Broker, regex("estate", ignore_case=T))~"ESTATE",
                                  TRUE~"OTHER"))
```

However, this is fairly timeconsuming with >100 unique brokers and more than 12500 combinations of handwritten brokernames in ~80.000 records.

I was wondering whether it would be possible to make this replacement using `mapply`, I haven't been able to so far, however.

Many thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

`Data$Broker` consists of all kinds of combinations in terms of spelling, information included, etc.

E.g.

```
Data$Broker <- c("Real-estate", "Real estate", "Real estate department 788", "Michael / REAL Estate")
```

Comment: Did any of these answers help you? If so, consider upvoting them and accepting one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `i` flag for case-insensitive regex and use `str_replace_all` -

```
library(stringr)

Unique_brokers <- c("REALESTATE", "ESTATE")

Data$Unique_brokers <-  str_replace_all(Data$Broker, 
                    setNames(Unique_brokers, str_c('(?i)', Unique_brokers)))
```

Answer (score 0):

A `dplyr` and `stringr`solution:

```
Data %>%
  mutate(Broker_unique = if_else(str_detect(Broker, "(?i)real(-|\\s)?estate"), 
                                 "REALESTATE",
                                 "ESTATE"))
        Date                     Broker Broker_unique
1 01-10-2020                Real-estate    REALESTATE
2 01-10-2020                     estate        ESTATE
3 01-11-2020 Real estate department 788    REALESTATE
4 01-11-2020      Michael / REAL Estate    REALESTATE
```

The pattern works like this:

- `(?i)`: make match case-insensitive
- `real`: match literal `real`
  -`(-|\\s)?`: match `-` OR  (i.e., one whitespace) **optionally**
- `estate`: match `estate` literally

Test data:

```
Data <- data.frame(Date = c("01-10-2020", "01-10-2020", "01-11-2020", "01-11-2020"), 
                   Broker = c("RealEstate", "REALestate", "Estate", "ESTATE"))

Data$Broker <- c("Real-estate", "estate", "Real estate department 788", "Michael / REAL Estate")
```